# PyBullet - How to set global coordinates of robot joints?

Tags: pybullet

I am new to PyBullet. Is there a way to set the positions of my robot joints using Cartesian coordinates as input? The function below requires angles as its input. I have looked through the documentation at https://docs.google.com/document/d/10sXEhzFRSnvFcl3XxNGhnD4N2SedqwdAvK3dsihxVUA/edit# but can't seem to find anything relevant. Any suggestions ?

```
p.resetJointStatesMultiDof(self._humans[human], idxes, values)
```